# MySQL Collation in Kamailio tables

Tags: mysql, github, collation, kamailio

For some reason I don't know, I have some Kamailio tables with `utf32_general_ci` collation (location in example) and others with `latin1_swedish_ci`.

I try to find answer on github repos (https://github.com/kamailio/kamailio/blob/4.4/scripts/mysql/my_create.sql) but collation is not specified.

That's right? Does matters? Which one it's right choice?

My Kamailio version is 4.4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is Kamailio?  What does it store in a database?

In general, all software today should be using full `UTF-8` characterset encoding.  In MySQL, the syntax is `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

You mentioned two `COLLATIONs`; they have to do with sort order, not character encoding.  The two mentioned correspond to character sets

- `utf32` -- 4 bytes per character quite wasteful of space; virtually no one uses it; there is no good reason (that I can think of) to use it today.
- `latin1` -- 1 byte per character; handles western Europe, but none of Asia.  It is an old default in MySQL (hence your tables having it).

I do not know the ramifications of trying to change Kamailio.

One thing to note in how MySQL deals with character set differences:  You must specify the encoding in the *client* when connecting to MySQL.  Then, when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing`, MySQL will convert (if necessary, and *if possible*) between the *client* encoding and *column* encoding.  Because of this automatic conversion, you will currently see nothing wrong for western European characters.  But Greek, Chinese, etc will be mangled/lost when attempting to store into `latin1`.

Comment: And then, it's transparent for the binaries?

Comment: @JavierValencia - _If_ the `CHARACTER SET` in the table can hold the characters and _if_ you correctly identify the encoding of the characters in the client, and _if_ there is a mapping between the two charsets, then MySQL will correctly change the bits on the fly (`INSERTing` and `SELECTing`).  The 'binary' _code_ is driving by static/dynamic settings.  The 'binary' data is stored the same across _Operating Systems_.  (Or are you asking something else?)

Comment: `utf8mb4` and `utf32` _probably_ can map to any other character set.  ("That's their job.")